# Gradle sync failed with java.lang.AssertionError

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I tried lots of methods but couldn't solve the problem.everything works fine but at the end gradle error :

Gradle sync failed: java.lang.AssertionError

android-studio 3.6
gradle 5.4.1

Comment: Run `./gradlew <task_name> --stacktrace` for more output, your current question doens't provide enough information

Comment: please put your gradle files code